# reset packet sent when receiving big TCP traffic

Tags: windows-xp, tcp

A client receives chunks of TCP segments from a server, which total 20MB or more. Sometimes the client will send RST segments to the server before terminating the TCP connection.  Before sending RST segments, I did not find any segments indicating zero window size, or, ACK behind.  What could be other reasons causing the RST?  This is a Windows XP client.

Comment: With segments, do you mean files that have a total filesize of 20 MB? Or fragments, that form a 20 MB packet? Can you make a screenshot from a wireshark capture?

Comment: A RST is a hard termination. Do you mean that the client sends a RST before all of the data has been transferred instead of sending a FIN after all of the data has been transferred?

Comment: @ott it's a stream of TCP segments, each of which is capped at 1500 bytes or so.

Comment: @joeqwerty  The client sent the RST after receiving about 10MB from the server, and then opened a new connection.

Comment: I think they want give you a hard time to capture to a whole file directly.